# Necessary and sufficient condition for the differentiability of a multivariate characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, differential-topology, characteristic-functions

$X$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d,||.||$ an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^d.$

Prove that the characteristic function $\phi_X$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to +\infty}xP(||X|| \geq x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty}E[X1_{\{||X||<x\}}]$ exists in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Is it possible to generalize this condition to obtain the differentiability at any point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d?$

Any ideas how to do it? Because it doesn't seem it's an obvious problem.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the special case $d=1$ ?

Comment: I thought you already had a solution for $d=1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Please take a look at [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).

Comment: Didn't find a thing in particular: after thinking, perhaps we should find a norm more convenient in order to make problem easier.